# ¿Por qué el condicional pertenece al modo indicativo?

Tags: tiempos-verbales

No consigo entender por qué la RAE dice que el condicional pertenece al indicativo (el modo de la realidad) si el condicional expresa la posibilidad:

> Me encantaría ir a una isla.
>
> Habrías podido avisarme.

Las acciones (de ir a una isla o avisar a alg.) no han sucedido en la realidad, en consecuencia no es algo real sino solo potencial. ¿Tenéis alguna idea de por qué es así?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me parece que es más un tema sintáctico que semántico. Mientras que el indicativo tiende a ser autónomo, el subjuntivo suele depender de verbos en modo indicativo.

Comment: A mí me enseñaron el asunto en la escuela (hace tres décadas) como "modo potencial". Creo que lo comenté una vez en este foro y fui corregido oportunamente.

Answer (score 3):

Tal como se explica en [esta página](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Potencial%20o%20condicional.htm), ha habido largas controversias sobre la inclusión del potencial o condicional en el modo indicativo o subjuntivo. Originalmente, se lo consideraba incluido en el **modo subjuntivo**:

> [...] las gramáticas decimonónicas encuadran habitualmente estas dos formas en el modo subjuntivo. Hasta en su edición de 1917, la Gramática de la RAE da *cantara, cantase* y *cantaría* como variantes del ‘pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo’ y *hubiera cantado, hubiese cantado* [y *habría cantado*] como variantes del ‘pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo’.

Inclusive en una época se habló de **"modo potencial"**:

> En la reformulación de la Gramática que lleva a cabo a partir de 1917, la RAE opta por retirar estas dos formas del subjuntivo, pero no las incluye entre las indicativas y, basándose en empleos del tipo de *Tendría entonces unos cincuenta años* o *Yo nada sacaría de engañar a usted*, crea un modo nuevo, el ‘potencial’, que indica el hecho “no como real, sino como posible” (RAE 1931: § 285).

Parece que en su vieja gramática Andrés Bello ya propugnaba la inclusión del condicional en el **modo indicativo**:

> Bello había dejado claramente establecida la pertenencia de *cantaría* y *habría cantado* al modo indicativo, basándose para ello en el parapelismo que muestran pares del tipo *Dice que esperará. / Dijo que esperaría. / Cuando llegues habré terminado el trabajo. / Dijo que cuando llegaras habría terminado el trabajo*.

Tal como decía en mi comentario más arriba, parece que la razón que ha primado es la sintáctica: **el indicativo es independiente, el subjuntivo es (explícita o implícitamente) subordinado**. Así lo explica la página citada:

> Descontado el imperativo, el resto de las formas verbales se reparte en dos grupos dependiendo de su compatibilidad con las modalidades del enunciado. Uno reúne las formas posibles con entonación interrogativa, como *cantas, cantabas, cantaste, cantarás, cantarías*. El otro engloba las que carecen de esta posibilidad: *cantes, cantases, cantaras, cantares*. [...] Se trata de los modos denominados indicativo (las formas del primer conjunto) y subjuntivo (las demás). Ambos términos son válidos como tales, aunque imprecisos y heterogéneos: en manera de designar, el indicativo “indica“, señala una determinada noción; **el subjuntivo alude a un comportamiento sintáctico (se subordina a algo)**. [...]

A pesar de que **la RAE incluyó al condicional en el modo indicativo desde 1973**, subsisten las discrepancias:

> Uno de los problemas de la clasificación de los modos en español es el del potencial. Amado Alonso y Henríquez Ureña nos dicen que “Los modos indican de qué manera encara el que habla la significación del verbo: el indicativo como real...; el potencial, como posible...; el imperativo como mandato, consejo, ruego o petición...; el subjuntivo como deseo o duda... Tales usos son los de la oración simple. El subjuntivo, además, se emplea en oraciones subordinadas”.
>
> El potencial, efectivamente, tiene unos usos peculiares, que no llegan a configurarlo como modo, para la generalidad de los tratadistas, pero que lo sitúan **entre el indicativo y el subjuntivo**. Es posible que su adscripción temporal, tan neta, al plano del pospretérito, haya privado a estas formas de su valor modal diferenciado. Así, temporalmente situado es, como tiempo, indicativo (el subjuntivo tendría sólo semitiempos), pero conserva muchas posibilidades de intercambio con las formas de pasado del subjuntivo. Simultáneamente, tiene usos especiales, para expresar aproximación o posibilidad: “tendría unos cuarente años”, a las que subyace un verbo de creencia u opinión: “creo que tendría ...”.» [Marcos Marín, Francisco: Curso de gramática española. Madrid: Cincel, 1980, p. 262]